# $\lbrace S_n\rbrace_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded , $\lim Sup \, S_n=\lim Inf\, S_n=s$ then $\lbrace S_n\rbrace_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $s$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits, limsup-and-liminf

If $\lbrace S_n\rbrace_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$  is bounded and $\lim Sup \, S_n=\lim Inf\, S_n=s$ then $\lbrace S_n\rbrace_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $s$.

*Proof*

Let us denote by $S$ be the set of subsequential limits, since $\lim Sup \, S_n=\lim Inf\, S_n=s$ then  by definition of infimum.
$\forall l\in S$ we have that $l\geq s$ and if $s^{\prime}$ is other number such that $l\geq s^{\prime}$ then $s^{\prime} <s$

And by definition of supremum
$\forall l\in S$ we have that $l \leq s$ and if $s^{\prime}$ is other number such that $l\leq s^{\prime}$ then $s^{\prime} >s$.

From here $\forall l\in S$ $l=s$ and hence every subsequence of $\lbrace S_n \rbrace $ have limit $s$ hence $\lbrace S_n \rbrace $ is convergent sequence and in fact their limit is $s$

What is wrong with this proof?
Any comment was very useful, thanks in advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Here it is another way to approach it for the sake of curiosity.

Notice that $m_{j}\leq S_{j} \leq M_{j}$, where
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
m_{j} = \inf\{S_{n}\in\mathbb{R}\mid n\geq j\}\\\\
M_{j} = \sup\{S_{n}\in\mathbb{R}\mid n\geq j\}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Then apply the squeeze theorem.

Comment: what is wrong in my proof?

Comment: Nice approach, which is the definition of  $s_j$

Comment: @JuanT it is just the sequence which you have provided. I have edited it in order to keep the notation.

Comment: The argue with this proof is , notice that $m_j<S_j<M_j$ as you define and then $\lim m_j \leq \lim S_j \leq \lim M_j$ and it means by squeeze theorem that  $\lim inf m_j=s \leq \lim S_j \leq \lim Sup M_j=s$ and hence $\lim S_j=s$ as requiered?

Comment: @JuanT That is the point of the argument.

Comment: What do you think of the argue above (in my proof)?